Can we apply $P(|X|\geq t)=2 P(X\geq t)$ for a discrete centered and symmetric random variable?
I am reading here that for a centered variable $X$ we have
$$P(|X|\geq t)=P(X\leq -t)+P(X\geq t)=2\cdot P(X\geq t)\tag{1}$$ I suppose $X$ has also to be symmetric in order to have (1). For a Rademacher r.v. $X$, which is centered and symmetric, we have that
$$P(X\geq t) \leq \sqrt{(1+t)^{-1-t}(1-t)^{-1+t}}\tag{2}$$ Is it correct to use (1) in order to write for a Rademacher r.v. $X$ that
$$P(|X|\geq t) = 2\cdot P(X\geq t) \leq 2 \sqrt{(1+t)^{-1-t}(1-t)^{-1+t}} \tag{3}$$ with $t < 1$.
In order to study the correctness of (3), I have tried to compute the upper bound of $P(|X|\geq t)$ using Cramer-Chernoff method. We have the logarithm of the MGF of |X|
$$\psi_{|X|} (\lambda) = \ln E[e^{\lambda |X|}] = \ln \left(\frac{1}{2}\left( e^{\lambda \cdot |1|} + e^{\lambda \cdot |-1|}\right)\right) = \lambda \tag{4}$$
Then we have the Chernoff's inequality
$$\operatorname P (|X| \geq t) \leq \exp (-\psi_{|X|}^*(t)) \tag{5}$$
where
$$\psi_{|X|}^* (t) = \sup_{\lambda \geq 0 } (\lambda t - \psi_{|X|} (\lambda)) = 0\tag{6}$$
with $-1 < t < 1 \stackrel{\lambda \geq 0}{\Leftrightarrow} - \lambda \leq t \lambda - \psi_{|X|} (\lambda) \leq 0$, which implies $\psi_{|X|}^* (t)=0$, which in turn implies $\operatorname P (|X| \geq t) \leq 0$ which combined with the fact that for every probability $\operatorname P (|X| \geq t) \geq 0$, we conclude that $\operatorname P (|X| \geq t) = 0$.
Am I doing something wrong? This means also that (1) can not hold for a Rademacher r.v.?
Could you please someone cast some light

Note that $(1)$ is possibly false for $t=0$, and definitely false for $t<0$.

I assume $t>0$ throughout my answer.
The first equality, i.e., $P(|X|\geq t)=P(X\leq -t)+P(X\geq t)$, is always true by definition.
The second equality, i.e., $P(X\leq -t)+P(X\geq t) = 2 \cdot P(X\geq t)$, is true if and only if $P(X\leq -t) = P(X\geq t)$. Centered (i.e., zero-mean) random variables do not necessarily have this property, as you are aware of. You are correct that the random variable being symmetric is a sufficient condition for this second equality to hold (and in fact necessary if you want it for all $t$, by definition).

Thanks for the answer. I did an edit in the OP, can you please take a look?

Possibly I am doing something wrong in the computation of $\sup$. Can you please take a look? If (1) holds, then computations (4)-(6) will provide us with
$$P(|X|\geq t) \leq 2 \sqrt{(1+t)^{-1-t}(1-t)^{-1+t}}$$
Am I wrong?
